# Culture-specific exact date parsing with and without leading zeroes

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a string value that represents a date, and I want to parse it into a DateTime. Parsing should succeed, and **ONLY** succeed, if the format is valid in the specified culture.

Example:
Parsing "2/1/2020" should succeed in en-US culture, but fail in de-DE culture.
Parsing "1.2.2020" should succeed in de-DE culture, but fail in en-US culture.

My attempts using `DateTime.TryParse` and `DateTime.TryParseExact` did not give the results I want.

This returns `false`, as expected, because the date is in en-US format, and the de-DE culture is used for parsing:

`DateTime.TryParseExact("2/1/2020", "d", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-DE"), DateTimeStyles.None, out date)`

but so does this because the "d" format requires leading zeroes for month/day values:

`DateTime.TryParseExact("1.2.2020", "d", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-DE"), DateTimeStyles.None, out date)`

I could use this instead, which returns `true`:

`DateTime.TryParse("1.2.2020", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-DE"), DateTimeStyles.None, out date)`

But then so does this, which is bad especially because it returns the wrong date (Jan 2 instead of Feb 1):

`DateTime.TryParse("2/1/2020", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-DE"), DateTimeStyles.None, out date)`

How can I do this, without resorting to culture-specific date time format strings for each culture?

Comment: `Parsing "2/1/2020" should succeed in en-US culture, but fail in de-DE culture.` are you sure? Hint: don't be. Besides what does `2/1` mean? In the US it's February 1. In almost every other country it's January 2. Getting the wrong value is *far worse* than getting an exception

Comment: In any case, both `DateTime.Parse` and `ParseExact` translate `/` to the locale's date separator. That's why  `DateTime.TryParse("1.2.2020", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-DE"), DateTimeStyles.None, out date)` works.

Comment: Finally `DateTime.ParseExact("01.02.2020", "d", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-dE"))` works while `DateTime.ParseExact("01/02/2020", "d", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-dE"));` throws. You can [check it in dotnetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/pFN9Ye)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: "Besides what does 2/1 mean?" If I'm specifying en-US culture, then it's clear that the date should be interpreted as Feb 1. The issue with getting wrong values is exactly why I don't want to use the standard DateTime.TryParse behavior, see the last example above.

Comment: So what do you want to do? You can't know what a date literal represents unless you know the culture. You can't guess the culture from the literal itself, except for specific cases. Why assume that `1.2.2020` is German instead of Russian? And the last example *does* throw.

Comment: What is the question after all? Leading zeroes work, despite the question's assertion. You can't use `/` with a `de-DE` culture, despite the question's assertion. In both cases, `ParseExact` or `Parse` would throws, while `TryParse` and `TryParseExact` would return `false`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: The use case here is a .csv file that I know the (supposed) culture of, which I want to validate. I want validation to fail if I know the file is (supposedly) in de-DE format, but I find a date in there that is not a valid German date.

Comment: That's why I said you shouldn't assume Germans use `.` in dates, or that only the US uses `/`. In any case, what you want *is the current behavior*. If you use `/` with `de-DE` you'll get either `false` or an exception.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: "you shouldn't assume Germans use . in dates" Why not? The German date format uses ```.```, not ```/```. As the question says, the current behavior is not what I need. Why would I ask otherwise? Have you actually tried the examples?

Comment: Because you just found out that `/` is common in Germany too. Because I work for an online travel agency and receive mixed date formats from airlines, both in Germany and Russia. Far more so in Germany than Russia. `Have you actually tried the examples?` I even posted links to `dotnetfiddle`. What you claim can't be reproduced

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: your dotnetfiddle isn't relevant because it is using leading zeroes, which is not what the question is about. Please check this fiddle to see all cases reproduced: [https://dotnetfiddle.net/FS865s](https://dotnetfiddle.net/FS865s). Also, any reason why you're so confrontational? "you just found out..." What makes you presume that I just found this out? You know my use case better than I do?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: Also, "you just found out that / is common in Germany too" - that is not even true. Source: I'm German.

Comment: You have mixed up different methods. `Parse`/`TryParse` don't use a *single* format, they work with any of the formats registered for a culture. On the other hand `ParseExact/TryParseExact` work only if a string matches an exact format. To match multiple format you have to explicitly pass them as an array. Using `Parse` when you want an exact match isn't going to work. It seems the only question is how to handle missing leading zeroes with `ParseExact`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: "It seems the only question is..." Thus, my posting here.

Comment: As for `Source: I'm German.` and I process German CSVs too. People may use one format but computers and ERPs another. Which is a pain. Furthermore, if `Parse` works in the `de-DE` culture it means that format is registered to work with `de-DE` *in the OS itself*. `Parse` and `TryParse` are meant to be lenient. They'll also handle `YYYY-MM-DD`

Comment: In `ParseExact` you can specify multiple formats in an array. `d` is a strict specification that [corresponds to a culture's `ShortDatePattern` exactly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings#the-short-date-d-format-specifier). If you want to allow other formats you have to specify them as well. This means you have to specify `d/M/yyyy` or `M/d/yyyy` as well as `d`, eg `DateTime.TryParseExact("1.2.2020", new  []{"d","d/M/yyyy"},CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-DE"), DateTimeStyles.None, out var date4)`.

Comment: For a few locales, you could keep the alternative patterns in a dictionary keyed on the culture. If you have a lot of cultures, you could replace `MM` with `M` and `DD` with `D` from the `ShortDatePattern` value: `var patterns =new[]{"d",ci.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern.Replace("MM","M").Replace("dd","d")};`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: Using "d/M/yyyy" doesn't always work either. For example, ```DateTime.TryParseExact("02/01/2020", new []{"d","d/M/yyyy"}, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("zh-TW"), DateTimeStyles.None, out var date4)``` returns a wrong/ambiguous date. I would like this to fail since the expected date format for Taiwan is yyyy/M/d. ```DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern.Replace``` is what I also came up with, but it doesn't feel clean and I'm not sure if it covers all edge cases.

Comment: It can be worse. [South Africa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_and_time_notation_in_South_Africa#:~:text=All%2Dnumerical%20dates%20can%20be,with%20non%2Dnumeric%20month%20designations.) uses YYYY-MM-DD, YYYY/MM/DD officially, but the common format is DD/MM/YYYY.  Unless dates are in the ISO8601 format (YYYY-MM-DD) there's no failsafe way to handle all locales *and* detect inconsistencies. To handle multiple formats, parsing has to be lenient. To detect discrepancies, it has to be strict.